# How to add active state to div using usestate hook?

Tags: reactjs

I have 4 divs and onClick I want a border bottom to be green only when one div is clicked but the first div remains default active.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

const MenuItems = ({ icon, title, color, tabNum, setTabIndex }) => {

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);




  return (

    <div style={selected?  {borderBottom:"2px solid green"} : null} onClick={() => setSelected(selected)}>
      <p
        onClick={() => setTabIndex(tabNum)}
        style={{ color: color }}
        className="p-1 shadow-md flex flex-col items-center justify-center cursor-pointer"
      >
        {icon}
        <span className="text-xs text-black">{title}</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MenuItems;
```

from what I tried, it selects all as active. Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would suggest you to :

1.render the 4 div via map() built-in method so u can have a unique index for each div

```
Array.from({length:4}).map((v,i,list)=>{
   // Never put the index as a key, i did it here only for 
   // learning purpose
   return (<div  key={i} style={selected === i ? {borderBottom:"2px solid 
           green"} : null} onClick={()=> setSelected(i)}>
           bla bla bla
          </div>)
})
```

2. modify ur useState hook as :

   const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);

i hope i answered your question .

Comment: it's a child component receving props from parent